# "ejb not bound" -- What could be the problem?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0

When I'm running my program, I get the following error:

> ... nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   ejb not bound

The error occurs at the start up when Java wants to create a certain bean.

The Bean is a *SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean*. Could it be that I ain't got the rights to access the naming provider URL although I can ping it?

When accessing the bean on my local JBoss there are no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the bean wasn't running on the remote service. No wonder it didn't work.

It found out through the jmx-console's `JNDIView -> list()` function.